# What is the best way to cleanly emogrify a Laravel blade template file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using [an emogrifier](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier) to format the results of a blade template so I can send it in an email.

```
$html = View::make('emails.notification', [
    'data' => $data
]);

$emogrifier = new Emogrifier($html, null);

$result = $emogrifier->emogrify();

// now I can send the result in an email...
```

This works as expected, but in the interest of clean code and testability, I would like to extend my blade template to emogrify HTML within the template itself. Something like this:

```
@emogrify
  <style>
    .red-text {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <p class="red-text">This text is red</p>
@endemogrify
```

...but it looks like Blade directives don't allow opening/closing tags like this. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have found any interesting solution I am interested.

Comment: @AsTeR I never found an elegant solution. I just emogrified outside of the blade template.

Comment: I ended up doing the same!

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I do my email blades in laravel (I generally don't use an emogrifier, but hope this helps):

> Create a base email blade (usually in resources/views/emails/email.blade.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
       /* Include styles for all emails here */
    </style>

    @section('head')
    @show

</head>

<body>

<div class="email-body">
    @section('body')
    @show
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then when I want to create an email, I extend the blade:

> Create a new file in resources/views/emails/new-user-email.blade.php:

```
@extends('emails.email')

@section('head')
    <style>

        /* Add additional styling here if you need to! */

    </style>
@stop

@section('body')

    <!-- Email body content here! -->
    <h1>Welcome new user!</h1>

@stop
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I'm wondering specifically about how to extend Blade with a custom directive that modifies a section of HTML. Or if there is some other clean solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you looked at [Extending A Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade) for adding your own directives?  It seems as though you will have to render the blade body regardless and then apply the Emogrifier.  I was merely offering an alternative as you asked "If there was a better alternative."  I find it generally easier to define a base email blade that has styling directed at email use as apposed to relying on an Emogrifier.